# Compojure app runs locally, but cannot find main class lein when deployed to Heroku

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen, ring

I have a small Clojure webapp built with ring and compojure. Although the webapp runs find locally on my laptop, when I push to Heroku the app crashes. The specific error from the logs is

```
 Starting process with command `java $JVM_OPTS lein ring server-headless 3000`
 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class lein
 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My `project.clj` look like

```
(defproject hn-clj "0.1.1"
  :description "foo"
  :url "http://foo"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [compojure "1.3.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.2"]
                 [clj-http-lite "0.2.0"]
                 [cheshire "5.4.0"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.13"]]
  :ring {:handler hn-clj.core.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}}
)
```

The entry-point for the application is in `src/core/handler.clj`

```
(ns hn-clj.core.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]
            [hn-clj.core.controllers.story :as story]
            [hn-clj.core.controllers.users :as users]
            ))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [limit] (story/index limit))
  (GET "/stories/:id" [id] (story/show-story id))
  (GET "/users/:username" [username] (users/show username)))

(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

Locally the app runs find with `lein ring server-headless 3000` and in my `Procfile` I have put

`web: java $JVM_OPTS lein ring server-headless 3000`

Although I haven't created a `main-` function, this doesn't prohibit the app from running locally, I don't understand why the app won't run when deployed to Heroku. How should I refactor the `handler.clj` or the `Procfile`?

Comment: lein is a build tool, and it and its plugins are not included in a deploy unless they are explicitly listed as dependencies (plugins are only for dev / build time, not for deployment)

Comment: I don't really no heroku, but everything I see with a quick search tells me heroku expects your app to have a working `-main`. lein plugins for running your app are great in development, but you should not count on them in your deployed server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procfile should be something like this:

```
 web: lein ring server-headless $PORT
```

To check your application can run properly on heroku, you can use a *foreman* port, which makes use of the procfile.

These days I am using [gaffer](https://github.com/jingweno/gaffer), and the documentation on Procfile for Heroku is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#setting-local-environment-variables).